# Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, we will be appointing some provisional Moderators to fill that role.

We need your help. Please nominate some folks you might like to see become the provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

## The Nomination Process:

- Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. You can use the `---` markup to separate the nominee's commentary from the original nomination. See the example below.

## Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation.
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

> ```
> <h2>[username](<main profile link>) </h2>
>
> <h2>[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>) </h2>
>
> Notes:
>
> <why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>
>
> ---
> ```
>
> <sup><sup>(this section is edited in by the nominee)</sup></sup>
>
> ```
> I accept/decline this nomination
>
> I am name/age/location/fun fact/all optional. I live in location, so I am 
> generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may 
> want to know about me are…
>
> etc.
> ```

Comment: With no offence to the nominees so far (honestly): I'd like to see at least one person with prior experience running for a position.

Comment: @overactor I don't find that a very big problem. Of course, it would be nice to have a moderator with experience, but I think that three rookie moderators would do a great job. Sites can vary greatly from each other, and, while past moderator experience can help, it can't fully prepare you to moderate another different site.

Comment: If you're downvoting nominations, **please comment your reasons**. This is more important for this than anywhere else, as it's about user behaviour now.

Comment: oooh, *deja vu* all over again :)

Comment: To people who were not here during the private beta: don't hesitate to nominate yourself if you think you'd be a good fit. There's still time to prove that you will be dedicated to this site, since the moderators will likely not be picked in any particular hurry.

Comment: As opinions may change as we see more of people and get to know how they react in different situations, would it make sense for someone with sufficient rep to make a trivial edit to all the answers so people are free to change their votes?

Comment: @trichoplax People agree with you, and it makes sense. I shall follow this order! :D

Comment: @trichoplax A better (but still hacky) solution is to [flag the question for conversion to community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55888/254929), which will convert all the answers also to wikis, allowing anyone to edit them. The best solution may be that if something significant makes you change your mind, just comment on the post and explain how and why your position changed. The community team is likely to pay far more attention to that than to the raw vote count when making decisions.

Comment: @Air even though votes are unlikely to be a major factor, I'd still like people to be able to. Otherwise the only opinions displayed are those of people who are confident expressing them. There are people who will vote in a secret ballot but will shy away from showing bias for or against a particular candidate.

Answer (score 20):

I'd like to nominate myself.

[image: profile for ArtOfCode at Open Source Stack Exchange, Q&A for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]
 

[image: profile for ArtOfCode at Open Source Stack Exchange, Q&A for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]


[profile for ArtOfCode on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3457374.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/3457374)

**On the topic -** I've been dealing with free and open source software since I started programming 10 years ago. I like to think I've learned a fair amount in that time, and I'd be able to bring that knowledge to the table. I've been on and around Stack Exchange itself for nearly 3 years, so I have plenty of network experience.

**Moderation -** I'm an avid reviewer, it seems: I spend a lot of time in the review queues and am regularly to be found in the top reviewers list. I'd like to be able to extend that further, to the flag queue, and help out more. I'm one of the top [users](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2685/artofcode) over on [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), and have spent plenty of time moderating through reviews there.

**Some thoughts -** I'm active, on Main, Meta and chat, though I do tend to answer more questions than I ask. I'm also keen to help the community work through how *we* want to develop: the topics that are within our scope are important to define and I can work together with everyone's input to help firm up our boundaries. This is one part of the mod's duty that I think is really important: ensuring the community remains involved, and that people don't think they can't help out.

<s>I'm away over the next week or so - 24 July - 1 August - so if you don't see a whole lot of me, that's why. That said, no doubt I'll find *some* time to drop by and see how things are going.</s>

Comment: This guy would be a great mod, he's really helped represent the community from the outside, helping to make link with organizations. He'd be an excellent mod :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 I agree

Comment: [Elsewhere on Meta](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/130/when-will-it-be-appropriate-to-start-electing-appointing-moderators/133#comment256_133) I raised concerns about the closure of the first version of this nomination question. You were one of the users to VTC that question. How do you address the appearance of impropriety in light of the fact that you are now the "fastest gun in the west" to nominate yourself this time around?

Comment: @Air Well noted. I was one of the fastest to nominate myself this time around because I was around in chat when [michaelpri suggested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22576525#22576525) opening a new nominations post. That said, I don't think being quick to volunteer is *necessarily* bad, and I am keen to help this site develop.

Comment: I'm kinda surprised that you consider

Comment: @Unihedron I think you may have accidentally

Comment: @Air I see what you

Comment: A potential moderator should use their votes carefully, which includes the appropriate use of downvotes. Can you explain why you have over 200 upvotes but only 7 downvotes? Surely you've seen some unresearched questions?

Comment: @curiousdannii Very true. Two major reasons, I think: firstly many posts here *are* of good quality, though I have seen and downvoted some posts worthy of it. Secondly, I feel downvotes are actually more harsh than they're painted, and especially to new users they're very off-putting - I'd rather just not upvote and leave a comment, coming back to downvote if the post hasn't improved. That said, I could do with voting more in general, including downvotes.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Good explanations! :)

Comment: What made you think [this revision](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/revisions/290/3) was necessary or appropriate?

Comment: @Air the fact that the thread was in danger of dropping off the front page of meta. Although our major users may have been here and voted and commented, it makes sense to have this post at least on the front page so that new users visiting meta can find it and participate.

Comment: It's already featured in the sidebar on both main and meta sites.

Comment: @Air true, but various posts on various metas have noted that plenty of users don't look at the sidebar or know what it means.

Answer (score 14):

I think kdopen would be a good candidate.

[image: profile for kdopen at Open Source Stack Exchange, Q&A for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]
 

[image: profile for kdopen at Open Source Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]


[profile for kdopen on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/908638.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/908638)

kdopen is a member since the start of the beta and is active. As a result he is one of the top-users. But not only that, he is also among the most active in the review-queues, one thing that you want of a mod.

His good work as a main-, a meta-user and as a reviewer makes him in my opinion a great addition to the mod-team.

---

### Accepted

I live in Santa Cruz, work in 'The Valley', and have been programming for over 40 years.

I have been a member since the definition phase on [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#History).

I didn't originally intend to stand for moderator as my job can be pretty demanding. I actually carved out hours each day for a few weeks to help launch this site and didn't know if I could keep devoting a large number of hours each day. But reading the theory of moderation link, it seems like I might be a pretty good fit for what they want, and what it involves.

Reviewing other people's work, resolving disagreements, and ... well ... moderating (or herding cats) matches well in two senses

- It's already a big part of what I do on a daily basis for my job, so I'm familiar with the requirements
- It can be dealt with in small chunks, grabbing ten minutes here and there. I have plenty of those; it's the big chunks that are hard to find.

I also tend to be process-oriented, which means following the guidelines and being prepared to 'measure thrice' before acting. But it also means being able to apply common sense and judgement in knowing when they are **only** guidelines.

My practical experience in the field comes from both contributing and taking a large project from closed to open source. I'm generally considered, professionally, to be even-handed and able to act impartially.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad to see you're on board :)

Comment: @kdopen Following guidelines is good, but are you also able to acknowledge that they're not always right and ditch those guidelines when appropriate and moderate purely based on the situation?

Comment: Definitely .. that's why I said 'guidelines' and not rules - I'll edit

Comment: Glad to hear it... you'd be a valuable addition to the team.

Answer (score 14):

I'd like to nominate Mnementh.

[image: profile for mnementh at Open Source Stack Exchange, Q&A for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]
  
[image: profile for mnementh at Open Source Stack Exchange, Q&A for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]
 [profile for Mnementh on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/046e0e4ef2fa48f8bf3162a9383c5b4e.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/046e0e4ef2fa48f8bf3162a9383c5b4e.png)

He has been a great contributor to this site all throughout the beta so far. He is currently the top user in reputation and he is one of the top participators on both main and meta. He has posted many great questions and answers. He is also an active participant on several other SE sites. I think that he would be a very good moderator :)

---

I accept the nomination.

I'm usually hesitating to accept such assignments, but I really like this community. I like how the questions developed, I liked the discussions in the chat or on meta, I like many of the users. So I want to see this site succeed. If people here think I could be a good moderator, than that is a possible way to help this site.

I'm 39 years old, and I live in germany. I work as a programmer, I've been programming since I was 12 (seeing others here or on SO, I'm a late starter). I came in contact with open source at the university and I'm interested in the concept since then. I also like how the ideas infected other areas and I'm a fan of creative commons licenses. I was two times juror for the [Free Music Contest](http://musik.klarmachen-zum-aendern.de/free-music-contest-2014-en), a project to promote music under CC-licences. I also like the progression of free books.

Cory Doctorow really inspired with [his speech at the 28c3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUEvRyemKSg) (I attended live). Really watch this speech, it gives some perspective.

Comment: Oh dear, you're network flair... It just doesn't want to pop up!

Comment: @Mnementh I very much enjoyed listening to the Cory Doctorow speech you linked. Especially when he [weighed in on our site naming debate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUEvRyemKSg&t=2757). ;)

Comment: @Mnementh A potential moderator should use their votes carefully, which includes the appropriate use of downvotes. Can you explain why you have 500 upvotes but only 3 downvotes? Surely you've seen some unresearched questions?

Comment: @curiousdannii: I think downvotes are for answers that are just factual wrong. Downvoting questions doesn't make much sense in my opinion, as if there is something wrong with the question it has to be closed.

Comment: @Mnementh The downvote arrow for questions says they should be downvoted if they don't show research effort, are unclear or are not useful. We have lots of questions which are perfectly on-topic, but show no signs of research. So I think it's still just as important to vote down questions as it is to vote them up. That said, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 11):

And... I'd *also* like to nominate overactor.

[image]
 

[image]
 

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/4535348.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/4535348)

While we haven't seen as much from overactor as we have from some of the other candidates here, I've noted his presence in the review queues (and especially in submitting edits...). He's helped us define our scope on Meta; he's been around talking over issues affecting the site in chat, and he's *definitely* got [Open Source experience](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25323/chatbot-dev). He'd be a very worthy addition to the mod team.

---

### I accept the nomination

I am overactor (or Rik in case anyone was wondering), I'm 24 years old and am working as an apprentice software designer in Switzerland. (Though I'm a Belgian) I might not be the most knowledgeable about FLOSS on this site, but I'm learning a lot. (this site has already proven valuable in that respect for me).

I usually keep half an eye on this site during european office hours, never forgetting to check the review queues and meta every once and again and come online a few times during the evening as well. My contributions to the main site, though not as quantitativly impressing as some other candidates, have almost all been aimed at pushing the boundraries of our scope with well thought out questions. (with mixed success)

It is nigh impossible to get me angry and I always try my best to think about the people behind the account. One of my deepest beliefs is that, with very few exceptions, people are all just trying to get by and do what they think is best. The best way to solve conflict, I think, is to communicate and try to figure out what people think it is they are achieving.

I'm comfortable making decisions when necessary, but will always prefer to hear other people's opinions when an issue is not pressing.

I'm the one who originally created this proposal and though I consider this site in no way mine (but rather as belonging to the community who shaped it and those who will continue shaping it), It is in a way still 'my baby' and more than anything, I want to see it succeed. No matter how far it deviates from how I originally imagined it. (or still am imagining it)

I'm nervous that I might not do this site justice as a mod, but seeing the other contenders, I know I'll have a good team to work with if I do make the cut.

Comment: I'll leave a comment here in case anyone wants to ping me.

Comment: @overactor A potential moderator should use their votes carefully, which includes the appropriate use of downvotes. Can you explain why you have almost 200 upvotes but only 7 downvotes?

Comment: @curiousdannii one reason is that for me close votes and down votes are different things with different purposes. If a question is off-topic, that's a close vote, not a down vote. Another is that when a post already has a negative score and doesn't have very big problems,  I often won't down vote afraid for overkill. A third is that I also actively use not upvoting as a measure for mediocrity. Mostly though, I'm positive to a fault, too much so. I think you're right and I'll try to use my downvotes a bit less sparingly.

Comment: @overactor Those are all good reasons IMO! :)

Comment: I will be on holidays starting tomorrow until the 17th of August. I hope I'll be able to be online rgularly during that time, but can't promise anything, since I don't know what the internet situation will be like.

Answer (score 8):

I'd also like to nominate Zizouz212 - so add 1 to the total votes on this post.

[image: profile for Zizouz212 at Open Source Stack Exchange, Q&A for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]
 

[image: profile for Zizouz212 at Open Source Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]


[profile for Zizouz212 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5390835.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/5390835)

<sup>Note: users with moderator tools will be able to see that Zizouz has previously deleted a self-nomination. <s>This is here in the hopes that we can persuade him to come back, because I think he'd be a great mod.</s> He's come back. We can celebrate.</sup>

Zizouz212 has been around since the start of the beta, and has really helped us form our scope. He's been editing, reviewing, commenting, posting and generally making good contributions to the site. He's also helped promote the site externally, by reaching out to organisations. He's been around Meta plenty, giving opinions and helping resolve discussions about the site.

There have been some actions some have disagreed with, as I'm sure there have been for every nominee here, but overall Zizouz has been one of the instrumental users in getting this site up and running, and would make an excellent choice for the moderator team.

---

Before I go blabbering on about myself, I need to say that I am mesmerized by the amount of support I've received. Thank you :D

I’m Zizouz212, and I would love to be a moderator pro tempore for this site. Coming from Toronto, I’m an enthusiastic young person who is eager about open source in his creative works as well as software. I usually check on at random points on a typical day between 07:00 and 20:00 EST, but as I’ve been developing some software, it’s been nearly every minute. I would love to see this site grow into an amazing site on Stack Exchange. I've been putting lots of effort into this site already.

As a community member, I find myself very involved in critical questions of tagging, scope and question quality. I’m active in the review queues, chat, and most importantly I’ve “hosted” a convention on Meta (That is, I was first to get the convention badge here). As a moderator, I would take an interactive role, engaging with the community as to their thoughts during the beta, and fulfill the roles of a moderator, while continuing to contribute to the community with questions and answers. I’m not afraid to voice my opinions, even if the community disagrees, and I step up for what I believe needs to be done to solve issues, big or small.

Comment: @zizouz212 please... You would make a great mod

Comment: @TrevorClarke He won't get that ping because he hasn't been active on this post.

Comment: In the interest of explaining a downvote, while I have no doubts about this user's level of interest or engagement, my strong impression has been one of quantity over quality.

Comment: Quantity over quality?

Comment: @Air thanks for explaining. I have to say my impression is altogether different - what gives you yours?

Comment: @Air might I also ask if the downvote on my nomination is yours? No worries if it is, but I'd be interested to know your impression of me if so.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Why don't I hop into chat. :)

Comment: Good idea, thanks.

Comment: As I said last time, I am concerned with your unilateral reversal of tagging efforts.

Comment: @Zizouz212 ping for ^ that comment

Comment: Wow, a ton of votes for me... 16 up and 7 down. Just... interesting! If someone wants to talk about me, feel free to come to chat :)

Comment: I have downvoted this candidate.  It has nothing to do with the candidate's age, and I think @Zizouz212 is a great *user* of this site. However, being mod sometimes calls for making judgement calls, and to me after, reviewing the many questions and answers posted by Zizouz212, they indicate to me that the candidate (IMNSHO) is lacking in knowledge about open source licensing and the open source development process. I find his *enthusiasm* and *eagerness to learn* appealing - but this does not make the candidate suitable as a mod. I also disagree with most of his unilateral tagging activity.

Comment: @FreeRadical I think those are reasonable valid concerns, and I appreciate your thoughts about my nomination. However, I am unable to understand the relationship between judgement calls, and my allegedly lack of knowledge. I think that I am knowledgeable in the development process. Also, I would like you to specify your disagreement with my "tagging activity." This had been brought by another user in which we had discussed. What exactly about my tagging activity do you disagree with?

Comment: I think your use of the "derived-works" and "derivatives" is unilateral. You're the *only* person using "derivatives" and responsible for 2 out of 3 uses of "derived-works". None of these words are meaningful in the context of open source or software. As for the development process, you've asked a string of low quality questions (i.e. showing lack of prior reserach) about how someone can take away freedoms from users. Example: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/can-i-force-additional-notices-in-my-open-source-project

Comment: Gentlemen, may I remind you this is what chat is for?

Comment: @ArtOfCode I thought we were supposed to discuss the *eligibility* of the candidates openly?  Chat is great for having *semi-private* conversations, but it is not suitable if one want to make a reason for downvoting *public* (as opposed to explain it to that specific person). I've *already* told Zizouz212 the same things in chat, and the response is that he/she want to do things his/her own way.

Comment: @FreeRadical Hmm. You have a point there. Normally, discussions of this kind would go to chat, which is why I suggested it.

Comment: I don't recall ever saying that I will do things my own way, however, we must bring it to chat in order to effectively have a conversation.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to nominate [Gilles](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/60/gilles).

I would like to nominate Gilles because he has made major contributions, providing his thoughts and solid opinions on meta, as well as many answers on main. His seemingly calm composure when handling issues on meta, as well as chat, make him an excellent candidate for the position. I hope he accepts.

### Declined

I'm already moderating three sites. Let there be new blood. Also, let me not spend more time moderating.

Answer (score 2):

[image: profile for curiousdannii at Open Source Stack Exchange, Q&A for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]


[image: profile for curiousdannii at Open Source Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]


[profile for curiousdannii on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3401915.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/3401915)

My rep is lower than many of the other nominees, which I don't consider to be a problem. On all my sites I am a slow poster, but I am a frequent contributor to community moderation. I have double Marshal on two sites, double Copy Editor on one, and I make sure not to neglect to downvote. On my top sites I have 2000+ reviews combined (I only have access to some of the queues.) I'm also a top Meta user, often in the top 5.

I [think our scope is](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22573595#22573595) [currently well-defined](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22573616#22573616), but we need moderators to help explain the nuances of it. The site description, tour page, and on-topic pages all need to be carefully crafted. I don't think that our site name needs to change, but we will need some Meta FAQ posts to explain that it is not limited to the OSI definition or to software. And during private beta, when everyone can vote to close and reopen, we've seen a lot of posts be closed and reopened repeatedly. We'll need mods to explain what our standards are on things like questions being too broad or opinion based. I'd like to think I'll be able to do that.

Comment: Ouch -3 votes already. Explanations would be welcome.

Comment: If you're going to down vote on a nomination, do say why. I think @curiousdannii has been very involved on this beta and has shown plenty of maturity. Even if I don't agree with all of his views: +1

Comment: I've seen less of you than perhaps I'd like in a mod. That said, I can't deny you're one of our top editors! Tell me, if a prolific poster takes it upon themselves to change up our tags without consulting people first, how would you deal with that?

Comment: @ArtOfCode If they're simply adding more detailed tags appropriately I wouldn't do anything. If they're reorganising the tag system as a whole I'd ask them to get more feedback on Meta first.

Comment: @curiousdannii thanks, that's the kind of thing I hoped you'd say.

Comment: I have upvoted this nomination but in light of your behavior in [this conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25581/discussion-between-curiousdanii-and-zizouz212) I would like to emphatically retract my support. Moderation can be relentlessly frustrating; you need to be able to engage with other users in the community without losing your cool - "ARE YOU SERIOUS?!?!?!?!?! Can you not read?" and "learn some humility dude" are not appropriate behavior, even in a semi-private conversation.

Comment: @Air I seriously cannot comprehend why so many people think the feature request tag should be misused.

Comment: @Air But I admit my behaviour then was not appropriate.

Comment: You say that the site name doesn't need to change, but you have started the "Alternate site name brainstorming" meta post, which is now featured. You have also added a number of suggestions there. What has made you change your position on this? I find that moderators would need solid, strong and stable positions (unless of course, something important happens, a perspective is revealed) in order to effectively moderate a site.

Comment: @Zizouz212 There's a difference from saying something *needs* to be changed and saying it would be beneficial. I don't think there's anything inconsistent about that.

Answer (score -2):

[image: profile for Trevor Clarke at Open Source Stack Exchange, Q&A for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]
 

[image: profile for Trevor Clarke at Open Source Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects]


[profile for Trevor Clarke on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/4970532.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/4970532)

My name is Trevor Clarke I am 15 years old, I live in Toronto. I am generally on the site between 07:30 and 21:00 EST, I have been a part of the Stack Exchange community for over 2 years. Throughout my years I have spent time doing front and back end web development along with licensing and other open source projects.

I have been with open source from when it was just a concept, now I have met many great people and have been able to ask and answer the questions of this site. If elected as moderator I would make sure that everyone's ideas and points are fairly expressed and will take every possible measure to insure fair judgement. In the past I have helped moderate and grow many sites and communities (not only on stack exchange).

While I may be fairly new compared to some users with 20k or more on their network profile, I have the dedication it takes towards open source projects! I will do my best to provide great moderation.

I love the Stack Exchange communities and would love the opportunity to help this one grow! If you elect me I will be dedicated to this site, and make sure it grows into a great SE community!

---

Note 7 July:

Regardless of my downvotes. I have done everything I can such as reviewing, talking in chat, and posting content. I also have multiple upvotes... I am not giving up!

To the review queues I go!

Comment: I thought I saw a post from you a few minutes ago, but the time on this one doesn't line up...

Comment: @KevinBrown He reposted it.

Comment: Yup needed a fresh start

Comment: @KevinBrown I am rewriting it.... One minute.

Comment: @KevinBrown Sorry for any confusion! :-)

Comment: As I said last time, your rep is mostly made up by unresearched questions. I'd like to point out you've only made 1 non-self edit. You however do have 30 reviews, which is decent for this stage of the private beta.

Comment: I try and review as often as possible

Comment: @TrevorClarke Which is why I commend you for that :)

Comment: Not voted yet. @TrevorClarke you currently spend many hours per day on the site, which is good. I have no problem with age, either. But you are also on your summer break. In a month or two, you will be back at school and that should be soaking up a large portion of your waking hours. How do you feel you will mix that with moderating?

Comment: @kdopen Oh trust me, with teachers going work to rule in Toronto (or Ontario for that matter), we'll have nothing to do with school, this is where we'll go. :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 The question is meant as a prompt for a way Trevor can strengthen his candidacy. But frankly, teacher's going 'work to rule' should mean you have **less** free time - because you'll need to spend more of it teaching yourself.

Comment: @kdopen These work to rule strikes that we have are going into its 4th year. Personally, I don't think it's a big issue - that being said, I hope I get a response from Trevor. I'm sorry if I jumped at it, I guess I'm a little over-enthusiastic when it comes to criticizing our education system. :)

Comment: " criticizing our education system" Ohhh don't start me on that ...

Comment: lol, I always make sure to get those kinds of opportunities - criticizing governments :)

Comment: @kdopen Well sure I will have to spend more time at school... That being said I get up at 6 school doesn't start until 9. I get out of school at 3, that gives me 6-7 hours I can spend on the site. Plus lunch...

Comment: Lol, exact same schedule as me :D Get up at 6, grab a bus at 7:15, get to school at around 8/8:15 school starts at 8:50 :)

Comment: On the days I have more homework I will finish that then moderate

Comment: @curiousdannii I wouldn't worry to much about editing. Editing is a small portion, and definitely not the most important. Also, many others take care of that. The quality of many posts hasn't warranted serious editing yet.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Editing is an important part of community moderation. If you don't participate in community moderation much now, which should we trust you to be a full mod?

Comment: Editing does not mean moderation. Making decisions and voting and reviewing AND editing is moderation. Editing alone does not mean moderation.

Comment: @TrevorClarke I know that, that's what I've been saying! You have mixed participation in community moderation. Which is okay! But for mods I'd want to see more.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks for your input. From my perspective I have been very consistent regarding my participation in the community moderation. Could you give me some examples? I would love to use this to improve!

Comment: @TrevorClarke When you come across posts, especially from new users, look if there's anything you could improve: tags, formatting, turning bare links into inline links (ie. http://blah to [blah](http://blah)). Keep voting, and look out for questions and answers which should be downvoted because of a lack of research, or being too subjective etc. Votes can always be reversed if the posts get edited, so voting should always be seen as a constructive action, even down votes.

Comment: That link example didn't work. Maybe this will. `http://blah` to `[blah](http://blah)`. But just keep going, reviewing, reading, voting etc. :)

Comment: @curiousdannii That being said however, I've seen very few if any posts that would qualify as being low quality. Looking at this candidate reviews one by one, they seem appropriate.

Comment: @Zizouz212 The site's only been in open beta for one day. The bad posts will come!

Comment: @curiousdannii For one day, and even then, I find that there have actually been posts of excellent quality (as opposed to poor quality).

Comment: I support you! :)

Comment: @Will Thank you. I will do everything I can to help this site grow!

Comment: I want to say a few things: Trevor has really given a few things to the site. Many questions may not have been of utmost quality, but they have provided many perspectives, and developing a project right now, I have surprisingly used many answers. This site has been a drastic learning curve for everyone: we've been blasted with community issues that I would consider unheard of with other betas. He's very cooperative and collaborative, and attempts to genuinely help the community in the ways in which he does best. People have strengths and weaknesses: Trevor has really shone with his strengths.